# Entity Framework Specifying Multiplicity

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I'm currently using entity framework code first with the following models (please refer below). 1 Category can contain many books and similarly 1 rental can also have many books.

```
public class Book {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public virtual BookCategory Category {get; set;}
}

public class BookCategory {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
}

public class Rental {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateRented {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
}
```

When I generate the DB, what I'm getting is the book table with both BookCategory_Id and Rental_Id.

### Book Table

```
| Id | Title | BookCategory_Id | Rental_Id |
```

However this will not work in my context as multiple rental can contain the same book. Is there a way where I can specify the relationship so entity framework will generate a new table which contains something as follows:

### Rental_Book Table

```
| Rental_Id | Book_Id |
|    aaa    |  book1  |
|    aaa    |  book2  |
|    bbb    |  book1  |
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that creating a many-to-many relationship between `Rental` and `Book` entities. In the `Book` entity add a `Rentals` collection navigation property:

```
public class Book {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public virtual BookCategory Category {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Rental> Rentals {get; set;}
}
```

Then, add this configuration in the `OnModelCreating` method of your context:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {

       modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                   .HasMany<Rental>(b => b.Rentals)
                   .WithMany(r => r.Books)
                   .Map(cs =>
                            {
                                cs.MapLeftKey("Book_Id");
                                cs.MapRightKey("Rental_Id");
                                cs.ToTable("Rental_Books");
                            });

  }
```

For more info about this kind of relationship check this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify that one Book may have many rental:

```
public class Book {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public virtual BookCategory Category {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Rental> Rentals {get; set;}
}
```

and then, is the magic is ineffective, you have to set up the relations:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasMany(x => x.Rentals).WithMany(y => y.Books)
```